# What is the significance of Hal Clement's comment about "Pancake in the Sky"?

Tags: hal-clement

In the essay "Whirligig World" at the back of Hal Clement's *Mission of Gravity* (about how the planet Mesklin was invented for the book) he states that he thought of titling the book *Pancake in the Sky*, "but Isaac Asimov threatened violence".

What does this mean?

Comment: I guess it would be the similarity of the title to Asimov's novel "Pebble in the Sky"

Comment: Not to mention, combined with that, the pun on the shape of Mesklin.  After all, Asimov isn't on record as having threatened Heinlein over *Tunnel In the Sky*.

Comment: These two answers: the shape of Mesklin (which was *highly* oblate) and the pun on Asimov's recent title (1950 for Pebble, 1953 for Mission of Gravity) explain it perfectly.  One of you should make this an answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The planet Mesklin, the setting for *Mission of Gravity*, is a highly oblate spheroid, with an equatorial diameter of 48,000 miles, and a pole-pole distance of about 20,000 miles. In the essay Clement mentions "The model I have of it is six inches in diameter and not quite two and a half thick", so calling it a pancake planet is certainly justified.

Clement was clearly on good terms with Asimov; later in the essay he described how they spent an evening together debating what the major liquid phase on the planet would be, eventually settling on methane. Between friends a bit of teasing is not unexpected, and the joke title "Pancake in the Sky" is clearly intended to echo the title of Asimov's novel "[Pebble in the Sky](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1406)", published four years earlier in 1950.

Comment: Yes, they knew each other well. They both lived in Boston and Asimov was just two years older than Clement.

Comment: @MarkOlson interesting!